# Nested Flexbox Rows Width of Longest Element

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to replicate the behavior of tables using flexbox, for greater predictability and control. [Here's a codepen of what I have currently.](http://codepen.io/caffinatedmonkey/pen/QydyOg)

Here's the SCSS:

```
.flex-table
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  flex-wrap: nowrap

.flex-table-row
  display: flex
  flex-direction: row
  flex-wrap: nowrap

.flex-table-item
  flex-basis: 0
  flex-grow: 1

.flex-table-item > :nth-child(3n + 3)
  border: 1px solid red
  flex-grow: 0
  white-space: nowrap
```

My question is, how can I get the width of the each element in a column to take up the width of its content or the width of the largest element in the column, whichever is greater?

Here's an image of what I have:
[image]

I would like the box of `Header 3` to equal the width of the other two elements. Also, if `Content 2-2` or `Content 3-2`, grows, I want all columns to expand to have an equal width of the largest column, similar a table. I know I can partially do this with `min-width`, but I want an approach which works with dynamic content of any width.

Comment: @AlvaroJoao I've tried using `min-width` and `flex-grow: 1` but `min-width` doesn't work with dynamic content, and `flex-grow: 1` takes up the maximum available space.

Comment: You may have to change the structure...flexbox isn't a replacement for tables.

Comment: @Paulie_D If there is a way to have the same effect with a fixed table (column taking up content width or width of widest element in column and other columns which fill in the remaining space), please fill me in and I will be forever grateful.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I'd use a table here... It's what you really want after all.

Comment: @Paulie_D How would I do it  (column taking up content width or width of widest element in column and other columns which fill in the remaining space) with a table with `table-layout: fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, to do this (with flexboxes) the header and the content below will need to be grouped in columns instead of the way you have it now in which all headers are in the same row. I believe the way I mention makes more sense anyways, but maybe you need something different.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tacc2tqr/1/) of what I am describing. As you can see, in each column each element will dynamically resize to the width of the largest element in that column. In addition, the flex-basis: 0 makes sure that every column resizes to the same width as the largest column. If the width of one column resizes, they all do.

Really all I did is switch from row to column:

```
.flex-table-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

Let me know if you have questions on this or if I missed the mark.

Comment: It works as specified if you add `white-space: nowrap` and `flex-grow: 0` to the just the column you want to exhibit the behavior. This is a good answer, but I can't use it because the flex-table is populated with angular2 and using rows instead of columns would require running an expensive filter to be run 5 times.

Comment: Sorry! That's the only pure CSS way I can think of. Would you consider a solution using javascript/jquery?